# If a question is modified is it proper to respond to the essentially new question with a new answer

Tags: discussion, etiquette

There is a question that was clarified by the asker enough so that putting a comment to my question may not be the best approach.

If the clarification substantially changes the question is there any problem with just writing a second complete answer?

Here is the question in question. 
[What are the security considerations for a javascript password generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352169/what-are-the-security-considerations-for-a-javascript-password-generator/1352201#1352201)

Comment: Do you mean "putting a comment to my *answer* may not be the best approach"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your initial answer is still relevant and potentially helpful to someone reading the question as it stands now, but with clarification you believe there may be an even better answer, then yes you can add a second answer. However, if the change in the question makes your initial answer wrong and/or unhelpful, then it would be best to delete the first answer, or completely rewrite it into the second answer.

Comment: Your answer helped me to decide when, in other situations, I may want to keep the old answer or completely replace it.

Answer (score 6):

Either that or, if your existing answer has no votes replace it with your new answer.

If you existing answer has some votes then it might be worth editing to state that it referred to an earlier version of the question.